# Convert csv to double list with c#

Tags: c#, list, csv, double

with the following code Im trying to read a csv file that contains double values and convert it into a list. If I want to print that list The output just contains **"system.collections.generic.list1 system.string"**. What is wrong in my code?

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\amuenal\Desktop\Uni\test.csv";

var contents = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split(';');

var csv = from line in contents 
          select line.Split(';').ToList();

    foreach (var i in csv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Comment: `ReadAllText` will give you one big string which contains the whole file. You are then splitting that on ";" (which means there are no ";" anymore) and you then split again on ";"(When there are none) .It is not logical. Did you mean to use `ReadAllLines`?

Comment: If the separator is ";" then how is it a CSV (comma separated value) file?

Comment: Jeah, I wanted to read the content of the file into a list. So I need to use ReadAllLines?

Comment: @Kevin with the years CSV have become an umbralla term for any file where fields are separated by a given caracter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a couple things wrong with your code.  First, you should most likely be using `ReadAllLines()` instead of `ReadAllText()`.  Secondly, your LINQ query was returning a `List<List<string>>` which I imagine is not what you wanted.  I would try something like this:

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\amuenal\Desktop\Uni\test.csv";

//iterate through all the rows
foreach (var row in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
{
    //iterate through each column in each row
    foreach(var col in row.Split(';'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(col);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do good. Hope this helps.

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\amuenal\Desktop\Uni\test.csv";
var contents = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

var csv = (from line in contents
            select line.Split(';')).SelectMany(x1 => x1);

foreach (var i in csv)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

csv is an IEnumerable of a List of string. (in other words, each "i" is a list of string).

You need two loops:

```
foreach (var list in csv)
{
    foreach(var str in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: @maccettura Right, misread a bit. It will be a list of list of string with the inner lists containing a single element each

Comment: I think the real issue is that he shouldn't be using ReadAllText, as litelite points out above. However, the code given does produce an IEnumerable of a List of string. Using my code will probably not give him the results he expects, but it will at least allow him to see a value instead of the type.